# Angular Directives Incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to make a simple directive in Angular. Doing something wrong :)

I want to output the content in 'directive.html' into the 'app-info' directive. The code works without the directive so I'm writing the directive incorrectly.

Cheers!

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
            <app-Info info="item"></app-Info>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular.js file

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.list = [
        {
            name: "Joe",
            age: 26,
            job: "Front-End Developer",
            skill: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Rob",
            age: 23,
            job: "Ruby Developer",
            skill: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Mark",
            age: 25,
            job: "Back-End Developer",
            skill: 0
        }
    ];

    $scope.skill = function(index) {
        $scope.list[index].skill += 1;
    };
}]);

app.directive("appInfo", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            info: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "directive.html"
    };
});
```

Directive html file

```
<li>{{ item.name }}</li>
<li>{{ item.age | currency }}</li>
<li ng-click="skill($index)">{{ item.skill }}</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few issues i noticed in the pasted code:

Firstly, you need to modify your directive.html to use `{{info.name}}` instead of `{{item.name}}` since your directive scope variable is info and not item.

Secondly, modify your html file. Directive name should be "app-info" instead of "app-Info".

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="angularApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
         <app-info info="item"></app-info>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Directive.html**

```
<li>{{ info.name }}</li>
<li>{{ info.age }}</li>
<li ng-click="skill($index)">{{ info.skill }}</li>
```

[[WorkingDemo]](https://plnkr.co/edit/RKcioddHpDpzA7kANr2M?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe your directive needs to be wrapped in a div tag, or another tag.  It must have one root element.